# MVC routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a search form on my page and I want to submit the form using GET. The search form looks like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegionName)

        <table class="plain">
            <tr>
                <td>From</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="Search" value="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    }
```

with a view model like this:

```
public class SideNavModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string FromDate { get; set; }
    public string ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have routes set up like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Search2",
        "Search/{CategoryName}/{RegionName}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}",
        new { controller = "Search", action = "List", CategoryName = "All", RegionName = "All", FromDate = "", ToDate = "" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Search1",
        "Search/{CategoryName}/{RegionName}",
        new { controller = "Search", action = "List", CategoryName = "All", RegionName = "All" });
```

So, when I actually do the search, the URL is sent to:

```
/Search?CategoryName=All&RegionName=SomeRegion&FromDate=20110301&ToDate=20110317
```

where I actually want:

```
/Search/All/SomeRegion/20110301/20110317
```

I'm not sure if it is significant but the way this is set up, the search needs to appear on every page. So, in the _layout.cshtml 'masterpage', I have this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("LoadNavigationSide");}
```

and in the BaseController, this:

```
public PartialViewResult LoadNavigationSide(SideNavModel model)
{
    // other code
    // ...
    return PartialView("NavigationSide", model);
}
```

(it needs to be like this since it does a little more than just return the model - so it can't be a simple @Html.Partial("NavigationSide") call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `method="GET"` on your form the HTML specification states that the user agent should send a GET request to the url used in the `action` attribute and append values as query string arguments.

If you use `method="POST"` on your form the HTML specification states that the user agent should send a POST request to the `action` attribute and write the values of form fields in the POST request body.

Conclusion: what you are trying to achieve is impossible with plain HTML.

One way to achieve this would be to use javascript and subscribe for the `onsubmit` event of the form, build the request url and manually redirect to it after canceling the default behavior. Example with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var url = this.action + '/' + $('#FromDate').val() + '/' + $('#ToDate').val();
    window.location.href = url;
    return false;
});
```

But personally I would stick with a POST verb.

Comment: thanks Darin. I am surprised that his isn't supported by the framework but i've got it working with the javascript method you have provided. As a side note, I want to use GET because if I were to do a search from some page, lets say '/Search/All/Region/20110101/20110201' and then did a search from that page again, a POST request would still have the old URL - it would not reflect the new dates

Comment: @quagland, that's not a limitation of the ASP.NET MVC framework. It is how the HTML specification is defined and browsers simply follow this specification.

Comment: right, that makes sense now that I think about it some more. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `SearchController` in your solution?  It sounds like you might be routing to the default route, which makes sense if you are declaring the default route before the custom Search routes.

Also, [Haack's Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), is a great tool for testing routes.

Comment: Yes, I do have a SearchController. The SearchController is receiving the parameters OK.

Comment: I've had a look at the Route debugger (very handy). If I have a url like: /Search/All/SomeRegion - I want this to fall through to the earch/{CategoryName}/{RegionName} route. At the moment, it is being picked up by Search/{CategoryName}/{RegionName}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try removing the part where you assign the default parameters.  It would seem like that is the only reason they could match

Comment: Well, that has fixed most of the problems I've been having. The whole thing functions correctly now but the search issue remains - the GET request on the form still returns a url like: `/Search/?CategoryName=All&RegionName=SomeRegion&FromDate=20110301&ToDate=20110327` It is OK if I use POST but that results in 'false' URLs. Do I need to tell the search form what route to use or something?